# Is it a problem to have two or more exactly same class name at different files?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-views

For my django application, I created class based views and each of them is defined at different file:

```
# foo.py
from django.views import View
...

class MyView(View):
  def get(...):
    foo()


# bar.py
from django.views import View
...

class MyView(View):
  def get(...):
    bar()
```

Actually, it is not necessary to have same class names because the views (the web pages) does not have the same content. They have different content created by `foo()` and `bar()`. What I want to ask is that is having the same class names at different files is contrary to Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) concepts?

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Each Python source file is it's own namespace so this isn't a problem. The only exception is if you are importing  symbols into your file. For example doing: `from foo.py import MyView` in bar.py might be problematic.

Comment: Ty for your comment, that's true. Actually, I wonder is having exactly same class names incompatible for OOP concepts.

Comment: In terms of OOP no, unless you are obliged to have corresponding files by the same name in the same folder (thinking Java). If the classes are under a different namespace you are ok. Now I think the question is more, should you do it in Django? I think you can but I maybe missing something in the overall picture of Django views recommended practices.

Comment: In practice, using same class names does not causes problem for django.